# What alternatives are there for replacing the D&D memorize and forget magic rules

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, house-rules

I'm starting a campaign and will be the DM. We are basing our system off the D&D 3rd ed. Most of us (players and myself) don't really like the rules surrounding Wizards / Sorcerers when they have to prepare / memorize their daily spells. I find that it limits the creativity of the player and adds complication to the flow of the story. Even though I don't like the system I do understand the logistics behind the rules and the inevitable explanations in-game.

I was curious what alternative systems other DM's might have come up with to replace the memorize / forget system of magic. Are there any known guides for this house rule(s)?

Possible ideas could be a mana based system, or maybe a saving throw style system that increase or decreases it's modifier to correspond to level of tiredness or concentration ability.

To narrow down this question to a more specific answer I am looking for an alternative magic system for D&D that:

- Allows the players to choose from all of their known spells at the time they wish to cast a spell.
- Be balanced in roughly the same proportions that the memorize / forget system imposes.
- Does not bog down the combat flow
- Offers the ability to use spells outside combat

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134355/is-the-magic-system-for-mages-from-monte-cooks-world-of-darkness-workable-in-d?r=SearchResults&s=1|139.0391

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest is to simply use the Sorcerer instead of Wizard - you get a small list of known spells, and a number of spells, and nothing else changes.

Slightly more effort, but more easily used for all classes...

**Spell Points**

Allow the usual numbers of known spells. Each spell costs spell points equal to twice it's level, with zero levels being treated as level 1/2. Total spell points available are found by totaling the number of spell levels availble per day and doubling. This does render the Sorcerer redundant, and the Bard can be switched to it easily enough (it's almost a non-change).

Comment: That's not unlike what was in the "2.5e" Player's Option books. As spell point systems go, it worked pretty well. +1.

Comment: I've used it since about 1985, so it's a coincidence... ub good ideas keep coming up in near identical forms again and again.

Comment: That spell point option dramatically powers up classes that are already the most powerful in the game, which he explicitly doesn't want.

Comment: I'm not sure how a spell point system would power up a spellcaster beyond what it already is.  You still have the same potential number of levels of spells per day.  You just have a little more variety and discretion by not having to select a specific list each day.  Sure, you can cast more higher level spells per day than before, but then you're left with no points for anything else and run out of abilities quickly.

Comment: I'm selecting this as accepted for it's concise nature. Although the other answers provide more detail and thought.

Comment: @BBlake Take a caster with 4/4/4/3/2/1 spells per day (Lvs 0/1/2/3/4/5)... he now has 4+8+16+18+16+10=72 spell points. He can cast 7 5th level spells, or 9 4th levels, or 72 0th level... that flexibility is REALLY empowering.

Comment: In a game where they're more concerned about not stifling caster creativity, I strongly suspect that they're not going to be doing much if any charop, and the effect of non-charop on group balance is likely to entirely overwhelm the small effect that this change would make.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Caster creativity is precisely the sort of thing that *makes them* massively more powerful than non-casting classes. It's only casters who do nothing by spam *fireball* and *cure wounds* that can appear to be balanced against Fighter and Monk. Also, the rules don't change depending on how hard you optimize; there's no such thing as a "char-op" game vs. a "non-char-op" game, there is just a continuum of optimization levels. And even at low ends of the spectrum, spellcasters have an edge and have a larger edge with this variant.

Comment: @KRyan Yes, there is such thing as a "non-char-op" game: it's one where people don't care about the power balance because their play objectives are orthogonal. Just because the power-balance axis exists in every game doesn't mean it's relevant to every game.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Exactly: choosing to ignore balance problems is not the same as not having them. Your statement was that having a "non-char-op group" would have an "effect [...] on group balance" – it doesn't, it just means that the problems of group balance are less or un-important. And the fact that he specifically requested that the suggestion maintain existing balance standards suggests that the group *does* care at least somewhat.

Comment: @KRyan Ah, I'm reading that differently. They asked for the proportion of spells to keep the same balance. I don't believe game balance is actually mentioned.

Comment: This isn't the Spell Points system found in Unearthed Arcana. Where is this from?

Comment: @Garan an option in Dragon for an older edition.

Answer (score 6):

**I don't believe there is a magic system in 3.5 with the guidelines you're specifically looking for. Spell selection limitation is at the heart of many factors of balance within 3.5.** Take the sorceror/wizard contrast for instance. The sorceror has access to a handful of spells throughout their career but gets more per day than the wizard, who can memorize/swap out spells on the fly. It's part of the balance - a prepared, thoughtful wizard can handle a greater spread of challenges than one who is neither precisely because of this limitation. I know of at least two separate ways to amend the spell system in 3.5, but not the memorize/forget system. I'll be checking back to see if anyone else has anything, though.

> Allows the players to choose from all of their known spells at the time they wish to cast a spell.

Some classes allow this, see the beguiler from PHB2 for instance.

> Be balanced in roughly the same proportions that the memorize / forget system imposes.

Unfortunately I don't believe there is a balanced system where this exists. Apart from radically limiting their spell selection or spells per day I can't think of how this might be accomplished.

> Does not bog down the combat flow

The system you propose where they can cast any spell on their list would bog down combat, I believe, and here's why: When I first played 3.5 I had a sorceror who got into the Mage of the Arcane Order prestige class. One of the benefits of this class (from *Tome and Blood* originally but it's republished more currently in *Complete Arcane*) is being able to cast any spell on the person's list, as you have in mind. All the caster had to do, essentially, was concentrate for one full round to bring the selected spell to memory. I slowed down combat a lot at first because not only was I new to the system but I had virtually no limitations on spellcasting within that system.

> Offers the ability to use spells outside combat

I don't quite understand this requirement. Rather I don't understand how it would be limited to only combat? Do you mean unlimited spellcasting outside of combat or something like that?

Comment: +1 for pointing out that there are a lot of classes that do get spontaneous casting. There's even a couple on the divine side to replace Cleric (Favoured Soul and Healer)

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, spellcasters such as Bard and Sorcerer do not prepare spells. They simply know only a select few spells that they can cast “spontaneously” without special preparation.

Other classes, namely the Beguiler (*Player’s Handbook II*), Dread Necromancer (*Heroes of Horror*), and Warmage (*Complete Arcane*) expand this idea: they cast spontaneously from their entire list, which is of course smaller than the Sor/Wiz or Cleric list.

These classes are still limited in how many spells of each level they may cast without rest, but that’s a matter of needing to recharge rather than forgetting spells.

The Dragonfire Adept (*Dragon Magic*) and Warlock (*Complete Arcane*) cast spell-like abilities called invocations. These may be cast at-will (no recharge), but these classes are restricted to learning only a very few invocations, which are usually much weaker than spells at the same level.

Meldshapers (*Magic of Incarnum*) and Binders (*Tome of Magic*) have supernatural abilities that can generally be used at will, though these classes have daily preparation sessions that dictate which subset(s) of their options they will use that day.

*Tome of Battle* has a very nice system for handling martial arts; some of these, for the mystic Swordsage class, are supernatural and quite “magical” (Desert Wind lets you throw fire, Shadow Hand has a number of ice-based attacks and at least one force-choke).

The *Tome of Battle* system is so nice that a very detailed homebrew magic system was made based on it. These “[Codices of Spellshaping](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=224508)” have been rather well-received by the 3.x homebrew scene.

Comment: I'm typing from my phone so I can't get a link to Spellshaping right now. Will edit it in when I get a chance, but I'll be extremely busy for the next week.

Comment: I found a GITP post that seems right. I'll link that, and if it's not the right one, it will at least serve well enough until you can replace it.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been some time since you asked the question, but consider looking into Thieves world. The spell system is very well done and doesn't use the "forgetme"-system that standard D&D does. It was made for D&D as a setting expansion, but i absolutely fell in love with the magic system.

features:

- No memorization or no spell slots; you take non-lethal damage equal to the spell level.
- take the chance and cast a higher level spell than your level allow.
- a spell can take more than one round to cast.
- cast your spells as rituals for a greater effect.

Comment: Here is a link to [Thieves World](http://www.thievesworld.info/roleplay/rpg-original.htm) And I think this is the [book on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1932442472) correct?

Comment: @Sukima Thanks for the links, that is exactly to book in question, I believe that this edition was made for D&D 3.0 or 3.5. The The Chaosium Box Set however is the way old edition (it was released in '81) and isn't specifically for D&D (it is more of a universal setting), so i wouldn't recommend using that for a D&D game.

Answer (score 2):

**Scribe Scroll Feat**

In D&D, any spell caster with the Scroll Scribe feat can write out a copy of their known spells, which they can then cast by reading from it, so there is no need to memorize it.

When I [played a wizard](http://www.scabard.com/campaign/171/character/233), I always had at least one scroll for every spell in my spell book.  This allowed me to have a large variety of spells handy without having to take up spell slots.  The disadvantage for the spell caster, is that it costs gp and xp to scribe scrolls.

**Microlite d20 Approach**

An alternative is to borrow from [Microlite d20](http://www.microlite20.net).  Spell casters can cast any spell they are capable of (based on level), and mana (hit points) are deducted according to a formula (Spell Level x 2) + 1.  0th level spells cost 1 mana, 1st level spells are 3, 2nd level spells are 5, etc.

In addition to not stifling creativity, your main concern, it greatly reduces the amount of bookkeeping and decision making (what spells to memorize) that only slows down play.

Microlite d20 is compatible with D&D and so uses the same spells.

Answer (score 0):

**Always Ready Spell (feat):**

- Sacrifice knowledge of spell X
- Then another (PREDEFINED) spell of the same level can be casted umprepared by using another slot of same level (including metamagic modifice spells of that level).
- Sacrificed spells can be changed each time you gain a new feat that has to do with metamagic, but number of sacrificed spells should never decrease (so you cannot go back from 4 sacrificed spells to 2).
- Reduce DC of the spell be few points to balance and prevent to use it to counter-spell (minimum 1)

Abusing that would result in a wizard with less spells than a sorcerer, so the coolprit would be to let just few spells be playable as "wildcard", but since you have reduced spells list it is likely you will use some prepared spells in a fixed way + some wildcard spell that is always playable.

**In example:**

- Sacrifice "AcidSpray" (lvl 1) in order to be able to cast "MagicMissile" anytime you want by consuming a level 1 slot that was filled with another lvl 1 spell  (in example "Mage Armor").
- Sacrifice "Acid Arrow"(lvl 2) in order to be able to cast "Still Magic Missile" (lvl 1 + still metamagic becomes lvl 2) anytime you want by by consuming a level 2 slot that was filled with another lbl 2 spell (in example "Fog Cloud").

Readied spells have a DC lowered: it just count as DC only one between Int modifier and spell level (wichever is higher).

This is not a total replacement for the rule, but a half-way of course.

I allow re-arrangin sacrificed spells because certain feats change the level cost of metamagic spells.

Comment: Is this a house rule spell system that you use at your table?  For how long have you been using this system?

Comment: 2 weeks so far, nice system.